# Program to ask user name and skip if they want to. I am getting many problems

Tags: python

I am writing a **Python** program that ***asks a user their name and allows them to skip if they don't want to enter their name by typing 's'.*** *typing 's' also makes the user's name 'Anonymous'.* But I have problems.
Since I am a beginner I am trying but I can't fix it.
**Please do help**
Here is the code

```
name = input('write your name')

while name != '':
    break


    if name == '':
        print('qwerty')

        while name is '':
            input(name)


            if name != 's':
                break


    elif name == 's':
        print('werty')
        name = 'Anonymous'




print('Hi ' +name)
```

Comment: Actually, this small piece of code is for a game I am developing and I need to get the update 1.5 out soon so please do consider helping me.

Comment: *What* problems? Give a [mre].

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre].

Comment: It's a bit pointless to have `break` as the first (unconditional) statement of a loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fist define a function that will as the name:

```
def ask_name():
    name = input('write your name : ')

    while True:
        if name != "":
            if name == "s":
                return "Anonymous"
            else:
                return str(name)

        else:
            name = input('Enter a valid name or "s" : ')
```

Then call it and it should be good

```
name = ask_name()
print('Hi ' + name)
```

Comment: Why not terminate with `s`? Thats what the OP wants...

Comment: Thank you Fredericka for the reply but i also want a while loop in the code because i dont want people to not give their name. Let me explain
 
The while loop asks the user continuously for their name until they enter it. If the user is not comfortable with entering their name, the program gives them an option to skip and the name will be given as 'anonymous'.

Comment: Here it goes i think this should fix it, i modified my previous post

Comment: Thanks! This works

Answer (score 0):

This will change your name to 'anonymus' on input 's':

```
name = input('write your name')

if name == 's':
    name = 'anonymus'

print('Hi ' +name)
```

Comment: The while loop asks the user continuously for their name until they enter it. If the user is not comfortable with entering their name, the program gives them an option to skip and the name will be given as 'anonymous'. 

Your answers work but I also want a while loop  to continuously ask the users name until they give their name or skip